# A few questions on convolution

Tags: functions, convolution

I am relearning the convolution of two real functions $f$ and $g$ defined as follows:
$$(f*g)(t)=\int_0^tf(u)g(t-u)du.$$

It satisfies some algebraic properties and also for Laplace transform, if we let  $F(s)$ and $G(s)$  denote the Laplace transforms of  $f(t)$ and $g(t)$,  respectively, then the Laplace inverse of the product $F(s)G(s)$ is given by the function $(f*g)(t)$.

**My questions**:

1. Does there exist an operation $f\star g$ such that if we let  $F(s)$ and $G(s)$  denote the Laplace transforms of  $f(t)$ and $g(t)$,  respectively, then the Laplace inverse of the convolution $F(s)*G(s)$ is given by the function $(f\star g)(t)$?
2. Is there a nice axiomatization of convolution using only the algebraic properties? If yes, what are some other examples of "convolutions" in other branches of mathematics? I am aware of some generalizations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) but am wondering if the idea can be extended to other fields such as topology or geometry.

Comment: What do you mean with "the product $F(s)  \ast G(s)$ " ? The convolution of $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ ? Then (if it converges) it is the Laplace transform of $ f(t)g(t)$ : $$\mathcal{L}[f(t) g(t)](s) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i \infty} F(z) G(s-z)dz = F \ast G(s)$$ as you can see, in the Laplace domain the convolution has a slightly different definition, you need to look at the Fourier transform for understanding why.

Comment: A good abstraction of the convolution are the LTI operators : $T$ is LTI if it is a linear operator $X \to X$ such that  $T[f(x-a)](y) = T[f(x)](y-a)$

Comment: @user1952009, thank you for your comment!! Yes, that is what I mean by $F(s)*G(s)$. To define a linear operator, all you need is a vector space $X$?

Comment: Look at the convolution on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ the vector space of sequences $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_n |a_n|^2 < \infty$. What we need for the convolution is that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group, so that $x-a$ makes sense. This generalizes to $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^n)$, $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $l^2(\mathbb{Z}_m^n)$, $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ ie. $L^2(G)$ for any abelian group $G$, and also to non-abelian groups (but then the convolution is not commutative anymore)

Comment: @user1952009, I can see why the construction generalizes to $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^n)$. etc., but why also to non-abelian groups? Also, to start with, do we at least need an inner product space so that $|a|$ is defined?

Comment: Try yourself, $L^2$ is there just for making sure $u \ast v$ converges, but you can extend to many more cases (for example $u \in L^1, v \in L^\infty$). The most abstract definition is there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#The_group_algebra

Comment: Thanks @user1952009 for your kind comments! They are very helpful.